# turn matrix or data.frame into a string with line breaks

Tags: r, string, dataframe, matrix

Need a function that turns a matrix or data.frame into a string with linebreaks so it "looks" the same.

i could write a loop. Is there a quick solution?

#### data

```
df <- mtcars[1:3,1:3]

               mpg cyl disp
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108
```

#### desired outcome

```
toStringFun(df)

new <-" mpg cyl disp\n21.0   6  160\n21.0   6  160\n22.8   4  108"
cat(new)
```

#### edit

please note: The columns should look nicely aligned with the right spacings

Comment: You may need to provide these details in the post because currently, it just looks like you need a function.  The others details are very minute and only if others looks so closely will identify it

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Im a little in a hurry. Next time i'll give more inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comnination of `capture.output()` and `paste` will work:

```
s <- capture.output(print(df,row.names = FALSE))
s <- paste(s, collapse = "\n")
> s
[1] "               mpg cyl disp\nMazda RX4     21.0   6  160\nMazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160\nDatsun 710    22.8   4  108"
```

Comment: almost perfect. I dont want the ROWnames. I try to set them NULL

Comment: `new = paste(capture.output(write.table(df, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")), collapse = "\n")`

Comment: @John perfect solution. Just add `capture.output(print(df,row.names = F))` to the code